# load external ajax content in a div

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I would like to load external ajax content (not .php but .aspx file) into a div, how can I do this using asp.net ajax, jquery ajax solution will also be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Look at [Webmethods](http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/03/13/asp.net-ajax-callbacks-to-web-methods-in-aspx-pages.aspx), and normal jQuery ajax will work aswell ofc.

Comment: Look at [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 2):

See this article:

[Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

```
public partial class _Default : Page 
{
  [WebMethod]
  public static string GetContent()
  {
    return "your content";
  }
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/GetContent",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
      $('#yourdiv').html(msg.d);
    }
});
```

**Using .load:**

```
$('#yourdiv').load('default.aspx/GetDate', function() {
   //done
});
```